# Q: Google Sheets - Filter entries that are less than 24 months apart

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Currently, I have a spreadsheet with Addresses and the Dates they have been sold.

I am trying to see which property addresses have been sold more than once since 2013. (Property Address shows up more than one time in my data)

I was able to accomplish this with conditional formatting and the following formula: =COUNTIF(C:C,C1)>1

[Spreadsheet Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRE9f.png)

Now I want to check if the properties that have been sold more than once, have sold within 24 months.

Example: 
1577 Wabash Street sold on 08/03/2015 and 01/13/2017, which is 1 year 5 months and 10 days apart. This would be a positive find.

5159 Trinity Park Drive sold on 06/28/2013 and 09/22/2015, 2 years 2 months and 25 days apart, which would be negative.

For this data, in the end, I only want to see 1577 Wabash Street come up.

01/13/2017  **1577 Wabash Street** 
08/03/2015  **1577 Wabash Street**
04/17/2017  1452 Wabash Street
10/30/2014  1446 WABASH Street
11/27/2013  1445 WABASH Street
07/14/2014  1415 WABASH Street
03/26/2015  1336 Wabash Street
05/10/2016  1287 Wabash Street
09/30/2016  1214 Wabash Street
09/22/2015  **5159 Trinity Park Drive**
06/28/2013  **5159 TRINITY PARK Drive**

I've tried different formulas with DATEDIF but couldn't get it right so far

**Thank you for any help!**

Comment: In principle, DATEDIF() should work, as should subtracting the dates directly one from another. Please post examples of what you tried and didn't work.

Comment: I just got it working using DATEDIF().

Using the following =DATEDIF(*First Date*, *Second Date*, "M").

Before I was trying to make it more complicated and do other filters within DATEDIF's

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide us with a sheet, so I made my own, and I did a few things to it to make the data easier to work with:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gA0rs1lESrrVxElQGZ1HfJyj-ozk3Qh2KNg7wynctzg/edit?usp=sharing

Please note, I created 3 sheets. The first Sheet, "Raw Data" is basically the raw data (that I copied and pasted from your question), and then normalized using the proper() function which basically puts all the addresses into Proper Case.

The second sheet "Filtered Data" does most of the work. Column B filters through the data and grabs 1 of each unique address. Column C lists the number of duplicates, and then on Column D, we print out the dates of any entries that have more than one sales date (transposed, to keep the data on one row). Then finally, once you select a time frame to check for sales (cell B1), Column A filters through the data and finds addresses that have Duplicates, and then finds out how much time spans between the last two sales dates.

On the "Variables" sheet, you can change the strings to suit your needs or change the months for the selection box.